# Getting the index of words in a dictionary from a file

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code for a simple store that will load products and prices from a file and load it to dictionary and then be able to use it into the program.. but i am trying not to hard code any of the code values so if the file changes it because un-usable.

my file = test.txt contains

```
banana:3
apple:4
```

Here what i tried so far

```
d = {}
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    name,score = line.split(":")
    d[name] = int(score)

print('''
Welcome to my store
What would you like to buy today

[1] banana
[2] apple
[3] orange

''')

menumain = int(input('Enter product number to continue: '))
if menumain == 1:
    value = int(input('how many banana you will buy'))
    new = d[name][0] * value
    print('You ordered',value,'banana(s), Which will cost you',new )
else:
    print('error! wrong menu')
```

what i need is

```
 new = d[name][0] * value
```

is it modify this line so it auto picks the index.. what user selected and from the product name. it use the product's value

in this case index 0 will try to get the value banana which is 3 but it is not working

Im doing this because if i write d['banana'] it will work but if something from the outer file is changed the code will break. So i need something so it works soft-coded

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple list of tuples [(product_name1,price1)] will be much simpler and do the job.

```
#menu printing:
for counter, product in enumerate(product_list):
   print(counter+1, product[0])

#getting the price
product_list[menumain[1]]
```